# microsoft.office.interop missing from visual studio when running as administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reference

If I run Visual Studio 2012 under a normal account, I have the Microsoft.Office.Interop.* choices when I go to add a reference.  However, when I run Visual Studio as an administrator, these options are missing.  I have tried reinstalling the Primary Office Assemblies, but this didn't help.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio, and this didn't help either.

Comment: Hard to repro this on my machine, these PIAs have been obsolete for the past 5 years.  You could of course just create the project with VS non-elevated.  Long term, it is best to wean yourself off of them, they have been thoroughly and elegantly replaced by the "Embed Interop Types" feature.  Office 2013 doesn't have them anymore at all.  Add the reference from the COM tab.

Comment: unfortunately we're still running Office 2010 and SharePoint 2010 in our environment, so I think I need to use them.  As far as running non-elevated, I usually get warned that I need to run elevated, so I do that by default.  Is there no trick to adding these interops when running elevated?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Office version, the Embed Interop Types feature works for any of them.

Comment: I've given up on figuring out how to get the PIA references working under admin, and was unable to find where the "embed interop types" you're referring to.  Ultimately I used a web reference to ExcelServices on SharePoint and was able to access the data I needed that way.